# understanding the concept of little endian and big endian

Tags: endianness

i am new in linux and  was learning about little endian and big endian .I am little confused why do we need them ?

Comment: If you have already read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness and have a specific question please go ahead and ask it. If you haven't, please do not expect us to write beginner-level primers for things that can be googled in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not related to linux but to the hardware. In earlier days big endian was common, but for x86 hardware has little endian.

For more info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 1):

It's simply method of writing bytes of multibyte numbers.

- Big-endian: from highest byte to lowest
- Little-endian: from lowest byte to highest